# Fourier Series Convergence Question

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

If I have the function

> $$f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> 1+x,  & -L \le x \le 0 \\
> 1, & 0 \lt x \le L
> \end{cases}$$

and I need to determine the points in the interval $ [-4L,4L]$ where the series does not converge uniformly and also where the series converges pointwise, how would I go about doing this?

I have already worked out the Full Fourier Series on $[-L,L]$.

Thanks

Comment: "The points...where the series does not converge uniformly"..has no meaning.

Comment: To start off, form a periodic extension of $f(x)$ and see where it isn't continuous

Comment: It is unclear what "the series" means. E.g., the function $f$ has no clear value at $\pm L$, and then it is talked about the interval $[-4L,4L]$.

Comment: Very true I haven't made that very clear. I have already worked out the Full Fourier Series of $f(x)$ on $[-L,L]$ so I assume that when it says series, it means the Fourier Series. I can post my answer to this part already if you think it will help in the answering of this question? Thank you